# push notification in ionic3 using phonegap push plugin

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ionic3, phonegap-plugin-push

I am new to ionic 3 and I have implemented phonegap push notification on an app I am building and I am not getting any kind of notification, not even alert message which should show when the app is registered, so can someone provide me with some help for this issue.

Thanks beforehand.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, Icon,AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { EventlistPage } from '../pages/eventlist/eventlist';
import { SigninPage } from '../pages/signin/signin';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages/signup/signup';
import { settingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { NewsPage } from '../pages/news/news';
// import { AddeventPage } from '../pages/addevent/addevent';
// import {EventdetailsPage} from '../pages/eventdetails/eventdetails';
import { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth'
import { ENV } from '../environments/environment.dev';
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild (Nav) nav: Nav; //can't inject nav controller in the constructor in the root component
  rootPage:any = EventlistPage;
  eventsListPage=EventlistPage;
  signinPage = SigninPage;
  signupPage = SignupPage;
  isAuthenticated = false;

  show: boolean = false;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any,icon:string}>;
  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    public platform: Platform, 
    statusBar: StatusBar,
     splashScreen: SplashScreen,
     private push: Push,
     public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    firebase.initializeApp(ENV);
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {

        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.rootPage=EventlistPage;//as firebase checks the user state asynchronously before the nav gets initialized
        this.show = true;
      } else {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        this.rootPage=SigninPage;
      }
      if(!this.isAuthenticated){

        //this.rootPage=SigninPage;
       this.pages = [
          { title: 'SignIn', component: SigninPage , icon: "log-in"},
          { title: 'Register', component: SignupPage, icon: "book"}
        ];
      }else{
        this.pages = [
          { title: 'news', component: NewsPage, icon: "paper"},
          { title: 'events', component: EventlistPage, icon: "albums" },
          { title: 'profile', component: ProfilePage , icon: "person"},
          { title: 'settings', component: settingsPage, icon: "settings"}



        ];
      }

    });


    // platform.ready().then(() => {
    //   // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    //   // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    //   statusBar.styleDefault();
    //   splashScreen.hide();
    // });
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.pushsetup();
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      if (platform.is('android')) {
        statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
        statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#000000');
    }
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  onLogOut(){
    this.authService.logOut();
    this.show = false;
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.rootPage=page.component
    //this.nav.setRoot(page.Component);
  }
  pushsetup() {
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      console.warn('Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device');
      return;
    }
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: '333057397510'
      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: false,
        sound: 'true'
      },
      windows: {}
    };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
      alert('device token -> ' + data.registrationId);
      //TODO - send device token to server
    });

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('message -> ' + data.message);
      //if user using app and push notification comes
      if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
        // if application open, show popup
        let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'New Notification',
          message: data.message,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Ignore',
            role: 'cancel'
          }, {
            text: 'View',
            handler: () => {
              //TODO: Your logic here
              this.nav.push(EventlistPage, { message: data.message });
            }
          }]
        });
        confirmAlert.present();
      } else {
        //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
        //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
        this.nav.push(EventlistPage, { message: data.message });
        console.log('Push notification clicked');
      }
    });

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin' + error));
  }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="dfd.dfd.dfd" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>hghg</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^2.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filechooser" spec="^1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.4.2" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.2.3">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="jjhgjgjhgjhgj" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

package.json

```
   {
  "name": "events",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^5.5.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-show-hide-password": "^1.2.6",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "^2.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.11",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "ghghfhgfh"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you configured your file google-services.json in the root of the project? In case you are building for IOS you have to configure the GoogleService-info.plist and the proper certificates on your account

Comment: I am adding it to android

Comment: you can have a look at this tutorial to check your firebase configurations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOOjamH1bAA

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the answer from phonegap plugin's issue page in github.
I removed android 7.0.0 and added 7.1.0
Then edited gradle files by rearranging maven and jcenter in the project.